# Github how to allow collaborators download project with config data without reveal the passwords?

Tags: git, github

I have read that I have to set in .gitignore to ignore the config.js file - which contain critical passwords.

However, I want collaborators to just download the project and enjoy everything works - including the DB connection an remote API secret keys.

But yet I do not want to reveal the actual passwords.
The config.js is hidden (not in GitHub at all).

I am using Github private repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want collaborators to just download the project and enjoy everything
>   works - including the DB connection an remote API secret keys.
>
> But yet I do not want to reveal the actual passwords.

These two things are mutually exclusive, you can't do both.

Collaborators should generally be working on their own resources. I usually create something like `config.js.dist` with some placeholder values and then put instructions in `README.md` that explain how you need to copy that file to `config.js` and then put in your own credentials and API keys.